# Wget and Wordpress, keep last trailing slash

Tags: wordpress, mod-rewrite, wget

I have a Wordpress based website that I scrap using wget.
I have articles under the form

```
http://mydomain.com/2011/01/

once scraped becomes 

http://mydomain.com/2011/01.html
```

I found out that when I enter

```
http://mydomain.com/2011/01/ 

in the navigator, URL gets changed to 

http://mydomain.com/2011/01
```

which is why, I think, it is considered as a file when I call wget.
I would be very grateful if someone has some clue on how to address this.

Comment: I think Wordpress's htaccess does this by default. However, I'm not sure whether there is a solution - `2011/01/` would probably simply become `2011/01/index.html`

Comment: Thank you for your help, I am currently trying to see if I can modify the htaccess to change that, I will let you know I I get it to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally managed to get to the result I wanted, in this way:
changing my permalink structure from

```
/%year%/%monthnum%/%postname%.html
```

to

```
/%year%/%monthnum%/%postname%/
```